# Vue JS rc-1 Passing Data Through Props Not Working

Tags: vue.js

In the [release notes for Vue 1.0.0-rc.1](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases), we are told

> "The inherit option has been deprecated. Alway pass data to child
>   components via props."

However, the Component API section says

> "$data can no longer be used as a prop."

I have been trying to pass data to child components of my root Vue instance, and have had no luck whatsoever.

In version 0.12.*, if you want/need access to a parent instance's data, methods, etc., you would simply add...

```
inherit: true
```

...to a child component.

Now, in attempting to access the parent data via props, I continue to hit a brick wall. Here is a simplified example:

app.js:

```
new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {
        authorized: false,
        currentView: 'welcome-view'
    },

    components: {
        'welcome-view': require('./views/welcome')
    }
});
```

views/welcome.js:

```
module.exports = {

    props: ['authorized'],

    template: require('./welcome.template.html')
};
```

views/welcome.template.html:

```
<div v-if="authorized"><p>You Are Logged In</p></div>
<div v-else>Please Log In</div>
```

Main View File (app.blade.php)

```
...
  <body id="app">
      <component :is="currentView"></component>
  </body>
...
```

The 'authorized' prop is not recognized at all this way. It works outside of the component (within the "app" id) just fine, but not within the template.

At the moment, I can access the data I need by using **$root** everywhere I need it. For instance:

```
<div v-if="$root.authorized"><p>You Are Logged In</p></div>
```

But, my understanding is that this is 'bad form' all around, [as the docs say](http://rc.vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent_Chain):

> Although it’s possible to access any instance the parent chain, you
>   should avoid directly relying on parent data in a child component and
>   prefer passing data down explicitly using props.

So, what I need to know is... *how* can I explicitly use props? I am clearly going about it the wrong way, since they are not available to my child components if I just list them in the 'props: []' array. What am I missing here?

At the end of the day, what is the best way (standards and practices) to refactor my current code to replace 'inherit: true', and still have access to the root instance data and functions? Any help/advice on this would be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See @StephenHallgren's answer on this page for the correct way to access props in the HTML.

As for the rest of it, (how to properly refactor code to replace 'inherit:true', I am including here [the answer I received from Evan Y.](http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/167/correct-way-to-replace-inherit-true-with-explicit-use-of-props-rc-1) on [the official Vue forum](http://forum.vuejs.org/), in case anyone else runs across this in the future.

His answer to the question posed above was:

> If you are fairly certain about the structure, you can use
>   $root.authorized.
>
> Alternatively, don't put the authorized state in the root at all. Have
>   a dedicated module for user state that can be imported in any
>   component. See
>   http://rc.vuejs.org/guide/application.html#State_Management

My take-away from this is that - where there are concrete, global variables that will not change, and the app structure is sound, it is okay to use **$root** (or **$parent** as the case may be), and - where elements have state that will sometimes change (such as whether or not a user is authorized/logged in), the key is to use a state management module.

Meanwhile, when passing down props between parent and child, one must declare the props in the props array, then bind them to the component in the HTML.

For example...

**app.js**:

```
new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {
        authorized: false,
        currentView: 'welcome-view'
    },

    components: {
        'welcome-view': require('./views/welcome')
    }
});
```

**views/welcome.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    props: ['authorized'],
    template: require('./welcome.template.html') 
}
```

**welcome.template.html**:

```
<div v-if="authorized"><p>You Are Logged In</p></div>
<div v-else>Please Log In</div>
```

**main HTML**

```
<body id="app">
    <component :is="currentView" v-bind:authorized="authorized"></component>
</body>
```

(or shorthand)

```
<body id="app">
    <component :is="currentView" :authorized="authorized"></component>
</body>
```

Comment: nice way to structure it

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and didn't realize that you also have to bind the value to the component prop like this:

```
v-bind:authorized="authorized"
```

or the shorthand

```
:authorized="authorized"
```

Here's an example of something that I had been working on that illustrates the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/2uqmj2jj/6/

Comment: Thanks, @StephenHallgren. This is correct in terms of getting the props to work within the component in the HTML. So, plus one for that. In terms of refactoring the current code to replace 'inherit:true', I am adding an additional answer below taken from Evan Y. via the official vue.js forum. Thanks for your help.